# Is there a way to get notification within your process when a remote process opened a process handle to your process from usermode

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to figure out who killed my process from taskmanager. Since taskmanager uses TerminateProcess and to Terminate a process remotely, it opens a Process Handle first.

So I am trying to look for UserMode ways to get a notification when a remote process tries to open a handle to my process.

I am aware there are possible solutions for this from Kernel mode using Driver Callbacks etc. But currently I am looking for User Mode possible solutions

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hi @IInspectable, I am trying to enumerate and get a notification as soon as another process tried to open a handle to my process. I am looking for ways to do this from UserMode from within my process.

Example I have an application named test.exe and when notepad.exe opens test.exe I would like to get a notification that notepad.exe opened a Handle to me.

Comment: @StackB00m There is no such notification in user mode.

Comment: A notification won't help anyway, because the attacker can just attack your notification handler! The only way to secure this for sure is to run in a different security context from any potential attackers. That way, you can deny access to that other security context.

Comment: That just re-iterated what you believe to be a solution. I was specifically asking about the problem. In case you still wish to pursue this route keep in mind that it will fail to produce a reliable solution in case two or more processes hold a handle to your process.

Comment: Although you cannot prevent it, you can have the system log it. Set a security audit alarm on your process's SACL to generate an event in the security event log when somebody gains `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access to your process.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to figure out who killed my process.

There is no *official* way to do that.

> I am trying to look for UserMode ways to get a notification when a remote process tries to open a handle to my process.

There is no such notification in user mode.

The only way I can think of doing this is to use `SetWindowsHookEx()` to globally inject a custom DLL into *every* running process, and then you can have that DLL manually hook `OpenProcess()` directly, such as with a detour.

The hook can then compare the function's `dwProcessId` parameter value against your app's current process ID, which you can store in a block of globally shared memory while your app is running, such as via `CreateFileMapping()`+`MapViewOfFile()` (see [Sharing Files and Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/sharing-files-and-memory) and [Creating Named Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory)).

Comment: Of course, the code that opens a handle to your process can just inject itself into your process *first* and disable your detector!

Comment: @RaymondChen Well, since my suggestion involves injecting code into the terminating process, the terminator wouldn't have to inject anything into the target first, it would just have to disable the detector running in its own process before then terminating the target.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am aware of API Hooking, but did not take that route, since AV or other endpoint security solutions would detect you injecting DLL or placing hooks and doing them on all processes is a lot noisy.

I discovered that using WMI Win32_ProcessStopTrace I can get an event trace of processes terminated, but unfortunately I have no way to identify which process terminated me

Comment: @StackB00m "*unfortunately I have no way to identify which process terminated me*" - because that information is not recorded anywhere.  My suggestion was simply to answer the question asked - "*get a notification [in user mode] when a remote process tries to open a handle to my process*" - and the only way to do that is to hook `OpenProcess()`, AFAIK.